# How to call on the conditions defining a 'while' loop to define an 'if' statement inside said 'while' loop

Tags: java

I just finished writing a Java program for the game "Tic tac toe" (I've been java-coding for a little over a month and this was my second biggest project so far). It works fine and everything; my problem is more about 'cleaning up' my code. The main action in the code is this big 'while' loop, the start of which involves this ugly statement:

```
while (contains(player1Selections, winningArray1) &&
contains(player1Selections, winningArray2) && 
contains(player1Selections, winningArray3) &&
contains(player1Selections, winningArray4) &&  
contains(player1Selections, winningArray5) && 
contains(player1Selections, winningArray6) &&
contains(player1Selections, winningArray7) && 
contains(player1Selections, winningArray8) &&
contains(player2Selections, winningArray1) && 
contains(player2Selections,winningArray2) && 
contains(player2Selections,winningArray3) &&
contains(player2Selections, winningArray4) && 
contains(player2Selections, winningArray5) && 
contains(player2Selections, winningArray6) &&
contains(player2Selections, winningArray7) && 
contains(player2Selections, winningArray8)) {
```

To clarify, here I am checking if the array list of player 1's co-ordinate selections or the array list of player 2's co-ordinate selections contains any of  the eight hard-coded 3-elements-long arrays for each possible victory pattern (which I convert in my boolean 'contains' method to array lists so I can use the 'containsAll' method for two array lists (I acquired this idea from a Stack Overflow forum, surprise surprise)).

Incidentally, it requires mentioning that I set my 'contains' method up so that contains(player1Selections, winningArray1) comes out true precisely when the array list of player 1's selections *does not* contain the array list of winning array 1 - that's why the loop works (it stops when one player's selections contains a winning array list). (Sorry about the confusing name.)

So what is my problem? My problem is that when either player 1 or player 2 makes the winning move, I need the phrase "Player [x] wins!" to come up before the final board is printed, showing the final positions of the noughts and the crosses (and when there's a draw, I need the word "Draw" to come up before the final board is printed), and the way I have solved this is super messy. The main part of the loop consists of code like this:

```
    if (togglePlayer == 0) {
    if (n1 == 0 && n2 == 0) {
    if (coordinate00.equals(" ")) {    // coordinate00 is a string
   coordinate00 = "X";
   player1Selections.add(0.0);          //the hard-coded winning-arrays consist of doubles in this format
   togglePlayer ++;}                   
   else { System.out.println("Position already occupied."); }
  }                   // this is closing the second 'if' statement but not the first, which gets closed only before I start writing out similar stuff for player 2
```

And here is what I have placed inside the last part of the loop (after all the statements like the one above), as a solution to my problem:

```
   if (contains(player1Selections, winningArray1) &&
  contains(player1Selections, winningArray2) && 
  contains(player1Selections, winningArray3) &&
    contains(player1Selections, winningArray4) &&
   contains(player1Selections, winningArray5) && 
    contains(player1Selections, winningArray6) &&
    contains(player1Selections, winningArray7) &&
    contains(player1Selections, winningArray8) &&
    contains(player2Selections, winningArray1) && 
    contains(player2Selections,winningArray2) && 
     contains(player2Selections,winningArray3) &&
    contains(player2Selections, winningArray4) && c 
   contains(player2Selections, winningArray5) && 
 contains(player2Selections, winningArray6) &&
    contains(player2Selections, winningArray7) && 
     contains(player2Selections, winningArray8)) {
       if ((!coordinate00.equals(" ")) & (!coordinate10.equals(" ")) &  
       (!coordinate20.equals(" ")) & (!coordinate01.equals(" ")) & 
         (!coordinate11.equals(" ")) &
     (!coordinate21.equals(" ")) & (!coordinate02.equals(" ")) & 
     (!coordinate12.equals(" ")) & (!coordinate22.equals(" "))) {
      System.out.println("Draw");
      System.out.println("\n" + coordinate00 + "|" + coordinate10 + "|" + coordinate20 + "\n" + "-----" + "\n" + coordinate01 + "|" + coordinate11 + "|" + coordinate21 + "\n" +"-----" + "\n" + coordinate02 + "|" + coordinate12 + "|" + coordinate22 + "\n");
      return;
  }
  else { System.out.println("\n" + coordinate00 + "|" + coordinate10 + "|" + coordinate20 + "\n" + "-----" + "\n" + coordinate01 + "|" + coordinate11 + "|" + coordinate21 + "\n" +"-----" + "\n" + coordinate02 + "|" + coordinate12 + "|" + coordinate22 + "\n");
```

Evidently, the really stupid thing about this last bit of code is that I've literally had to repeat verbatim the 'while' loop conditions for my 'if' statement, even though the 'if' statement is still inside the 'while' loop itself. I had to do this, since I couldn't figure out any more concise way of making sure that the program prints the board straight away only if the game isn't ending.

Now, I do have an idea for how to make this less messy, but I don't really know if it's possible... Basically, I'm just wondering if there's any way to'call on' my earlier 'while' loop conditions instead of writing them out again for the 'if' statement. I want to say 'The conditions for this if statement are exactly the same as the 'while' loop which are still in effect.'

This question may be unanswerable, but knowing that this is an impossible thing to do would also be useful.

Comment: You could create a function that tests all of these conditions for you, and returns just true or false.

Comment: "*I just finished writing a Java program…*" so is this Java or JavaScript?

Comment: make your big list of conditions a function

Comment: function is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Make your "winningArray1" through "winningArray8" a List of arrays.  Let's call that List "winningMoves".  If player2selections is your own custom class, you can add to it a "contains" function that iterates through the whole list.  Then your loop would look more like:

```
while (player1Selections.contains(winningMoves) 
    || player2Selections.contains(winningMoves)) { ... }
```

Some board games can be simplified by representing the board as a single String, then using String operations like `board.contains(" ")` instead of spelling out each coordinate.